# Create a list of CiviCRM newsletters group by CiviCRM group

Tags: views, civicrm

I have created a drupal view based on CiviCRM Mailing. I tried to display the recipient group(s) but it's seems to be neither in the field list, neither in the relationships.

Each CiviCRM Group represent a mailing list and we are sending a newsletter to one group at a time. Ultimaly, what i want to display is :

```
Group 1 :
* date - newsletter 1
* date - newsletter 2

Group 2 :
* date - newsletter 3
* date - newsletter 4
```

What could be the best way to solve this problem ?

Comment: purely off the top of my head could you create a relationship in your view to CiviCRM Groups? If so, this might then give you access to the fields you need.

Comment: No. Took a look and that won't work. Maybe start with a View of CiviCRM activities (a mailing is logged as an activity) and relate that contacts and their group membership?

Comment: Didn't try after all, activity doesn't associate with group and i don't need contact information. It could lead to a super slow query. Thanks anyway.